# Need help for Xamarin android Localization in files XML

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, localization, visual-studio-2019

I use this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization#basics). But I can’t change the text in the String resource. Thus, I cannot automatically update text in XML files using the construction - `@string/id`.
I created two resources `Language.resx` and `Language.uk.resx`. In each I created one line and this works. I also added folder `values-uk` and added file `String.xml` to it - this does not work for me.

This is my code:

```
Localization.Resources.Language.Culture = new CultureInfo("ru");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resource string.xml:" + Resources.GetText(Resource.String.test_string));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resource Language:" + Localization.Resources.Language.test_string);
Localization.Resources.Language.Culture = new CultureInfo("uk");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resource string.xml:" + Resources.GetText(Resource.String.test_string));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resource Language:" + Localization.Resources.Language.test_string);
```

My debug output

- [0:] Resource string.xml:Russian
- [0:] Resource Language:Russian
- [0:] Resource string.xml:Russian
- [0:] Resource Language:Ukrainian

[image]

My file values/string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Localization</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="test_string">Russian</string>
</resources>
```

My file values-uk/String.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Localization</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="test_string">Ukrainian</string>
</resources>
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The is Working. 
Must set property `strings.xml` of the files as `AndroidResource`, and for files `*.resx` you need the properties of the `EmbeddedResource`.
It is important!
You can use this code:

```
        Localization.Resources.Language.Culture = new CultureInfo("ru");
        Java.Util.Locale.Default = new Java.Util.Locale("ru", "RU");
        Resources.Configuration.Locale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resource string.xml:" + Resources.GetText(Resource.String.test_string));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resource Language:" + Localization.Resources.Language.test_string);
        Localization.Resources.Language.Culture = new CultureInfo("uk");
        Java.Util.Locale.Default = new Java.Util.Locale("uk", "UA");
        Resources.Configuration.Locale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
        Resources.UpdateConfiguration(Resources.Configuration, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
        Finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.Class);
        StartActivity(intent);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resource string.xml:" + Resources.GetText(Resource.String.test_string));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resource Language:" + Localization.Resources.Language.test_string);
```